# Javascript: forEach method within a function?

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, foreach

I'm new to JavaScript (I've used python for ~3yrs, and I'm currently trying to pick up the basics of JS syntax.) I am using codewars to facilitate learning.https://www.codewars.com/kata/5bb904724c47249b10000131/train/javascript

This problem gives the prompt

```
function points(games) {
  // your code here
}
```

The rules are:

```
if x>y -> 3 points
if x<y -> 0 point
if x=y -> 1 point
```

My naive approach is to create a function which receives an array as an input and apply a forEach method to every element therein. However, I'm triggering the following error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'else'`

```js
games = ["0:3","1:2","3:2"]

function points(games){
  let p = 0;
  games.forEach(
    function(game){
    let x = game.split(':')[0];
    let y = game.split(':')[1];
    if(x>y){
      p = p + 3};
    else if(x=y){
      p = p + 1};
    else {
      p = p + 0;
    };
  });
};
```

I'd like to better understand (A) why this error is beginning triggered and (B) what is the right way to accomplish this effect.

Edit: I likely need to cast x and y as a numeric type, however this isn't triggering the current error.

Comment: You've got a missing `}` in your code

Comment: `};` <-- that is not how you do if statements. Look at the syntax on MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else and you are doing assignment, not comparison.

Comment: @epascarello not sure what your comment tried to point out: a `;` is certainly not needed here, but it's also not "wrong": it simply does nothing. Sure, it's silly to put one in, but `if (x) { ... } ;;;;;;;;;;` does exactly the same as `if (x) { ... }`: a semi-colon in isolation is simply a noop.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans It is going to produce *"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'else'"* so yes, it does produce an error.

Comment: ah, in that case it would have been a good idea to mention _which_ of the various `};` you were commenting on (given that there are three).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some things to know about JS when you're coming from Python: the modern Array type has [*a lot* of utility functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), so the code you've written can be done with just a few calls, and a ternary (which I *really* wish Python supported, like every other modern language)

```js
function score(games = []) {
  // we could manually sum values, or we can use reduce() to do that for us.
  return games.reduce( (tally, game) => tally + calculateScore(game), 0);
}

/**
 * fun fact about JS: functions are "hoisted" i.e. they all get "moved"
 * during initial read-in to the top of the file, with their ordering
 * made entirely irrelevant: any function can have a function body that
 * calls any other function, because they're all at the same declaration level.
 */
function calculateScore(game = "0:0") {
  let [x, y] = game.split(":").map(parseFloat);
  return x > y ? 3 : x < y ? 0 : 1;
}
```

This uses some elementary modern JS:

- [default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters), basically the same as you'd use in Python,
- [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), which are kind of like lambdas but also *nothing like them*. They're pretty important to know about though, if you want to write modern JS.
- [array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), which can make summing values much easier, or much harder, depending on how complicated your code gets,
- [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) which turns strings into floats (fun fact: every number in JS is a float, which is why you integers only go up to 2^53: past that `(n+1) - n === 1` no longer holds)
- the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), which Python is sorely lacking.

Also quite importantly: note that where you see `parseFloat`, what really happens is that [array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) calls `parseFloat` with two arguments: the element, and its index in the array. For `parseFloat`, this is fine, because it only takes one argument. However, if you were to naively use `parseInt`, things would go horribly wrong: [it takes two arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), namely a string, and a radix.

Comment: Good answer, but does not actually answer the user's problems in their code.

Comment: It does, by teaching them how to write modern JS, which is clearly their intention coming to JS from Python. Especially when it comes to JS, not every code answer is "fixing the code problem by preserving as much of the post's code as possible", sometimes (heck, oftentimes) it's "teaching them how to write modern code instead".

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans - thank you! The brackets thing is new for me and threw me for a loop. Thanks for pointing out some best practices :)

Answer (score 1):

forEach is not the best approach for this question. This question can be done with reduce function, which can be used to calculate the accumulated sum for an array.

```js
const games = ["10:3","1:2","3:2", "3:3"]

//forEach approach
function points(games){
  let p = 0;
  games.forEach(game => {
    const [x, y] = game.split(':').map(parseFloat);
    x>y? p+=3 : x===y ? p+=1 : p+=0
  })
  return p
}


//reduce approach
//second parameter in reduce function is the initial value, which is 0 here
function pointsReduce(games){
  const sum = games.reduce((accumulate, game) => {
    const [x, y] = game.split(':').map(parseFloat);
    return accumulate+= x>y? 3 : x===y ? 1 : 0
  },0)
  return sum
}


console.log(points(games))
console.log(pointsReduce(games))
```

Comment: Remember: splitting strings yields strings, which means 10 would be considered less than 2.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you messed the curly brackets positions. They has to be right before else:

```
 if(x>y){
      p = p + 3;
    } else if(x=y){
      p = p + 1;
    } else {
      p = p + 0;
    };
```

Comment: Still not going to work right. You copied over another error

Comment: hmm, it doesn't count?

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is caused by the semicolon (`;`) that you put at the end `if` scopes:

```
if { ... }; else // unexpected token
```

LE: also, you have a bug in the second check, you're assigning the value of `y` to `x`. In Javascript comparisons are done with `==` or `===`.

To expand a bit on equality comparisons:

- `==` will attempt to cast the values before performing the comparison (eg: 1 == '1' => true)
- `===` is a strict comparison operator that will only return true if both operands are of the same type and value (eg: 1 === 1 => true, 1 === '1' => false)

Here's a working example of your code:

```js
function points(games) {
  let p = 0;

  games.forEach((game) => {
    let x = game.split(':')[0];
    let y = game.split(':')[1];
    if(x > y) {
      p = p + 3;
    } else if(x === y) {
      p = p + 1;
    } else {
      p = p + 0;
    }
  });
};
```

Below you'll find some other examples.

1. Using array spreads and dropping the branch which adds 0 to the sum

```js
function points(coordinates) {
  let p = 0;

  coordinates.forEach((coordinate) => {
    const [x, y] = coordinate.split(':');
    if(x > y) {
      p = p + 3;
    } else if(x === y) {
      p = p + 1;
    }
  });

  return p;
};
```

2. My favorite approach when it comes to readability:

```js
const points = (coordinates) =>  coordinates
  .map(coordinate => coordinate.split(':'))
  .reduce((points, [x, y]) => {
    if (x > y) { return points + 3; }
    if (x === y) { return points + 1; }
    return points;
  }, 0);
```

Answer (score -2):

Your code has a bunch of syntax errors. You are using too many semicolons. You do not add them on every line. You are working with strings and not numbers. You are not going a comparison in your else if, and you do not return anything form the method.

```js
function points(games) {
  let p = 0;
  games.forEach(
    function(game) {
      // no reason to do work twice, split once
      const parts = game.split(':')
      const x = +parts[0]; // convert to a number
      const y = +parts[1]; // convert to a number
      if (x > y) {
        p = p + 3
      } else if (x === y) { // comparison is == or === and no semicolon
        p = p + 1;
      } else { // <-- we do not add semicolons to the blocks on if/else
        p = p + 0;
      } // <-- we do not add semicolons to the blocks on if/else
    });
  // your function did not return the calculation total
  return p
};

const games = ["0:3", "1:2", "3:2"];
const result = points(games);
console.log(result);
```